# Setting the job priority in YARN

Tags: hadoop, hive, hadoop-yarn, hadoop2, hortonworks-data-platform

My cluster (HDP) is using YARN capacity scheduler. 
The nameNode UI shows Version 2.7.1.2.4.3.30.
I am trying to set the job priority to HIGH in my hive script:

```
set mapreduce.job.priority=HIGH;
```

However I see not difference in the allocation of resources.
I cannot see the property `yarn.scheduler.fair.preemption` in the yarn-site.xml.
Moreover what is the equivalent property for Tez?

Answer (score 0):

Because you make use of Hadoop 2.7.1, you have to explicitly set yarn.scheduler.fair.preemption in yarn-site.xml. Not setting this to true will result in the prioritising not working, because the default value of yarn.scheduler.fair.preemption=false.

Regarding your question about Tez, there is no equivalent. You may want to read more about how pre-emption works [here](https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.6.5/bk_yarn-resource-management/content/preemption.html)!